# Check whether a string is in a list at any order in C#

Tags: c#, linq

If We have a list of strings like the following code:

```
        List<string> XAll = new List<string>();
        XAll.Add("#10#20");
        XAll.Add("#20#30#40");

        string S = "#30#20";//<- this is same as #20#30 also same as "#20#30#40" means S is exist in that list
        //check un-ordered string S=  #30#20
        // if it is contained at any order like #30#20 or even #20#30  ..... then return true :it is exist

        if (XAll.Contains(S))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your String is exist");
        }
```

I would prefer to use Linq to check that S in this regard is exist, no matter how the order is in the list, but it contains both (#30) and (#20) [at least] together in that list XAll.

I am using

```
var c = item2.Intersect(item1);
                if (c.Count() == item1.Length)
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: var c = item2.Intersect(item1);
                if (c.Count() == item1.Length)
                {
                    return true;
                }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    Func<string, string[]> split =
        x => x.Split(new [] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (XAll.Any(x => split(x).Intersect(split(S)).Count() == split(S).Count()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your String is exist");
    }
```

Now, depending on you you want to handle duplicates, this might even be a better solution:

```
    Func<string, HashSet<string>> split =
        x => new HashSet<string>(x.Split(
                    new [] { '#' },
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    if (XAll.Any(x => split(S).IsSubsetOf(split(x))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your String is exist");
    }
```

This second approach uses pure set theory so it strips duplicates.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: @MikeBluer - `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>` so `Intersect` does work. I test all answer in LINQPad before posting.

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'IsSubsetOf' and no extension method 'IsSubsetOf' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MikeBluer - The second solution return `HashSet<string>`, not `string[]`. It's a new definition of `split` from the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should represent your data in a more meaningful way. Don't rely on strings.

For example I would suggest creating a type to represent a set of these numbers and write some code to populate it.

But there are already set types such as [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) which is possibly a good match with built in functions for testing for [sub sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx).

This should get you started:

```
var input = "#20#30#40";
var hashSetOfNumbers = new HashSet<int>(input
       .Split(new []{'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(s=>int.Parse(s)));
```